# Using If, Vlookup and Match statements but receiving "Compile Error Expected: end of statement"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compilation, vlookup

I have been working on the following code where there are multiple tabs on an excel spreadsheet.  It is supposed to perform a Vlookup on another tab with a table showing various security types and fields with either a "Yes" or a "No".  Depending on the field, it will either perform the BDP function or return "#N/A Field Not Applicable".

I tried using double quotes but still receive an error after the following line

```
Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(EQUITY, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=""Yes"", ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")""
```

How am I able to fix this or did I miss any quotes?

VBA below:

```
r = 2
While Cells(r, "A") <> ""
    c = 2
    For c = 2 To 79
                    'Cells(r, c) = "=BDP(Cells(" & r & "," & c & "), Cells(1," & c & "))"
        If InStr(RC1, "EQUITY") <> 0 Then

            Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(EQUITY, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=""Yes"", ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")"

        ElseIf InStr(RC1, "GOVT") <> 0 Then

            Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(GOVT, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=Yes, ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")"

        ElseIf InStr(RC1, "CORP") <> 0 Then

            Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(CORP, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=Yes, ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")"

        ElseIf InStr(RC1, "INDEX") <> 0 Then

            Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(INDEX, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=Yes, ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")"

        ElseIf InStr(RC1, "COMDTY") <> 0 Then

            Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(COMDTY, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=Yes, ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")"

        ElseIf InStr(RC1, "MTGE") <> 0 Then

            Cells(r, c)"=If(VLOOKUP(MTGE, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$7, MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=Yes, ""=BDP(RC1,R1C)"", ""#N/A Field Not Applicable"")"
```

End If

```
    Next c
    r = r + 1
Wend
```

Comment: it should be `Cells(r, c).Formula = "=If..."`

Comment: it should also be `MATCH(B4, 'Mandatory Field Control'!$A$1:$CA$1, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
Cells(r,c).Formula = "=Formula Here"
```

Edit: Also you have to are missing double quotation marks around `Yes` in

```
MATCH(B4,'Mandatory Field Control'!$B$1:$CA$1), FALSE)=Yes
```

in all of the lines but the first.
And as Jeeped mentioned your `Match` function should be updated to include `0`, or `1`/`-1`, depending on what you want it to return.

As a matter of personal preference I would also use `Select Case` instead of `If Then` for readability:

```
Select Case True
    Case(RC1 Like "*EQUITY*") 'I assume RC1 is a variable
        Cells(r,c).Formula = "=Formula here"
    Case(RC1 Like "*GOVT*")
        Cells(r,c).Formula = "=Formula here"
        ...
End Select
```

Comment: I wasn't specific but my comment about the MATCH also included a change from `$B$1:$CA$` to `$A$1:$CA$`. Unless of course, the OP intentionally wanted to offset by 1 column.

Comment: I have made the changes as suggested and the error no longer appears.  I'm actually having trouble with executing the VBA.  When I run it, there is no output (ie BDP function or N/A Field Not applicable not on excel)

RC1 is meant to refer to the cell and currently when r=2. C=2. RC1 is supposed to be B1 in this case.  I am not sure if I am referring it correctly?